# data structure in express

Tags: node.js, express, javascript-objects

I am building a web application with expressJS as the server where users can log in with their credential. I am trying to save each user registered details in an object like this :

var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
var regform = document.getElementById('regisform');

const saveName=(e)=>{

```
    let fnames = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    let lnames = document.getElementById('lname').value;
    let unames = document.getElementById('uname').value;
    let address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    let city = document.getElementById('city').value;
    let email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    let mobile = document.getElementById('phone').value;
    let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    let rpassword = document.getElementById('rpassword').value;




 var dB = {
        first:fnames,
        last:lnames,
        username:unames,
        address: address,
        city:city,
        email:email,
        mobile:mobile,
        password:password,
        rpassword:rpassword
    }

console.log(dB)
e.preventDefault();
```

}

regisform.addEventListener('submit', saveName)

But I am confused on how to achieve that each unique user registered is saved without affecting the other. How do I set this up with expressJS?

Answer (score 1):

If I undestand your question quite well : Saving Used to the database, you can achieve that using Mongoose by creating a mongodb(mongoose) connection, create a schema (data Model) and run the save or insert mongodb statement. To avoid duplicate, in your schema, make your important fields unique like : firstname : { type : string, unique : true, ...} and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your response but this project requires me to use a data structure to save users details without using frameworks like MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your structured DB as a json file. for example as an array of user objects when user login load the json file and parse through it see whether user credentials exist in the the array objects.

When creating you can append the new object into the array and save the json file.

Eg data structure of your json file.

```
[
{   first:"WhateverDataYouWantToStore",
    last:"WhateverDataYouWantToStore",
    username:"WhateverDataYouWantToStore",
    address: "WhateverDataYouWantToStore",
    city:"WhateverDataYouWantToStore",
    email:"xWhateverDataYouWantToStorex",
    mobile:"WhateverDataYouWantToStore",
    password:"WhateverDataYouWantToStore",
    rpassword:"WhateverDataYouWantToStore"}//1st object,
{ 2nd object}, //2nd object

]
```

By right one would normally call the real database like Mysql/firebase..etc to query for the user information.

Comment: Yes Marcia. That was so helpful from you. Thanks alot